# Purpose of Established Connections When Running Ignite Server

Tags: ignite

When I start my Ignite server app in addition to the expected listening connections I see around 20 additional connections in an "Established" state when using netstat -a. The listening ports are well documented but what is the purpose of these other connections? Each time I start the app the ports seem to increment.

[image]